# Maintaining Referential Integrity on Insert with NHibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have figured out a lot about nhibernate, but this seems to be my final hurdle of not understanding what is going on. So here is the problem.

I have a basic databas structure:

```
Shows:
ID [Pk]
CountryID [Fk]
Name

Countries:
ID [Pk]
Name
```

CountryID has a foriegn key reference from shows to countries table primary key, and countries is already populated with preset values that will rarely change.

Here is my Mapping Files

```
    public ShowMap()
    {
        Table("Shows");

        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name)

        HasOne<Country>(x => x.CountryOrigin)
            .Cascade.All()
            .ForeignKey("CountryID");
    }

    public CountryMap()
    {
        Table("Countries");

        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
```

I am *almost* sure it is a mapping problem, but when I do an insert into shows and I have a country attached to it. *It tries to insert a new country into the database instead of using an existing one in the database already*. **Which seems to be the main problem. I don't know how to do an insert properly where it uses an existing record in the DB.**

Finally, here is an example of me trying to do an insert not know really what to do.

```
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            Show s1 = new Show();
            s1.CountryOrigin = new Country { ID = 2, Name = "Japan" };
            s1.Name = "Liar Game";

            _session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(s1);
            tx.Commit();
            tx.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
```

**So the question is how can I insert a new show and have it reference an existing record in the countries table?**

---

**Update 1** I have reworked it to use a has many relationship because I was reading that a has one probably isn't the right way to go. Still have same problem, here is the code changes. These also reflect code changes in comments.

Insertion Code:

```
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            Show s1 = new Show();
            s1.CountryOrigin.Add(_session.Get<Country>(2));
            s1.Name = "Liar Game";

            _session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(s1);
            tx.Commit();
            return true;
        }
```

Mappings:

```
    public ShowMap()
    {
        Table("Shows");

        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name)

        HasMany<Country>(x => x.CountryOrigin)
            .KeyColumn("ID")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }

    public CountryMap()
    {
        Table("Countries");

        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
```

Still getting the cannot insert null into CountryID like was mentioned in one of the comments.

**Update 2** Doing some a bit of testing/debugging the:

```
            s1.CountryOrigin.Add(_session.Get<Country>(2));
```

Does what it is supposed to do and gets the correct country, but the problem happens on insert. So this makes me think it is more mapping problem.

Comment: Just a pedantic point: you don't need `tx.Dispose()`. The `using` statement will call `Dispose()` for you.

Comment: is that true even if I am returning true just after the tx.dispose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one-to-many relationship between country and show with show on the many side. So Country should be mapped using `References`:

```
public ShowMap()
{
    Table("Shows");

    Id(x => x.ID);
    Map(x => x.Name)

    References(x => x.CountryOrigin, "CountryID");
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is what solved it. And your description of it actually makes me better understand how reference works. Good short and simple explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Session.Load to get your Country object:

```
s1.CountryOrigin = _session.Load<Country>(2);
```

Session.Load says "I know that a record exists in the db with this ID. Create a proxy of that object for me, without bothering to go to the database". You could also use Session.Get, but that would create an extra db trip.

Comment: That is what my thinking was in what I was reading, but when I try that code I get. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CountryID'" as an error for an insert. This is the reason I am so confused. Even though I thought I found the answer and conventional wisdom says it should work it doesn't.